# Why is a prompt inside an alert execute before the alert prompt?

Tags: javascript

This might be a newbie question, or just plain dumb because I might just not be realizing that this is jsut like the higher level functions, like currying or the other I forgot the name.

Anyways

```
alert(prompt().slice(0,250));
```

Why is prompt executed before alert?

The only thing I can think is that it’s a higher level function.

Comment: Parenthesis are evaluated from the inside out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Okayyy. So I was right kind of.  Thank you. I

Comment: If `alert()` was executed first, what value would you expect to be passed to it and why?

Comment: There is no such thing as a higher level function. What does exist, is higher *order* functions, that do at least one of the following things: 1. Accept one or more function argument(s); 2. Return a function.

Comment: Same answer as why this evaluates to 48.....  3 x (4 x (2x2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your example has nothing to do with currying, or higher order functions.**

You are passing an argument `prompt().slice(0,250)` to `alert()`.

To know **what** to alert (or **pass** to whatever outer function is in place), **the argument needs to be evaluated first**.